# My Ruby calculator program acts like I didn't enter a valid operator

Tags: ruby, calculator

I have started learning Ruby today and so far I am loving the easy to read syntax! However, I have made a calculator app to learn the language and am struggling to get it to work. Below is the code for the app.

```
def add(first_number, second_number)
    first_number + second_number
end

def subtract(first_number, second_number)
    first_number - second_number
end

def multiply(first_number, second_number)
    first_number * second_number
end

def divide(first_number, second_number)
    first_number / second_number
end

def mod(first_number, second_number)
    first_number % second_number
end

def main()
    puts "First number: "
    first_number = gets

    puts "Operator (+, -, *, /, %): "
    operator = gets

    puts "Second number: "
    second_number = gets

    if operator == "+"
        result = add(first_number, second_number)
    elsif operator == "-"
        result = subtract(first_number, second_number)
    elsif operator == "*"
        result = multiply(first_number, second_number)
    elsif operator == "/"
        result = divide(first_number, second_number)
    elsif operator == "%"
        result = mod(first_number, second_number)
    else
        result = "Invalid operator. Please try again."
    end

    puts "Result: " + result
end

main()
```

It keeps going to the else and printing invalid operator and I am unsure why. Am I making a stupid mistake, or am I going about this program the wrong way? Thank you in advance and sorry for such a simple question, I have only started learning Ruby today :)

Comment: Hint: Remember input often contains a trailing newline character, so always fetch with `gets.chomp`.

Comment: Tip: Use `case` instead of a jumble of `if` and `elsif` statements. Even better, use a lookup table, like `{ "+" => :add, "-" => :subtract, ... }` which you can use in conjunction with `send` to make it very easy to add new methods, or even put the method itself in that look-up table as a lambda. You could also leverage the fact that those are already valid method names, so `first_number.send(operator, second_number)` is good enough for Ruby!

Comment: When debugging issues like this, `p` is your friend: `p operator` would be extremely illuminating.

Comment: From the [docs about `gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets): _The separator is included with the contents of each record._. BTW, you can debug this kind of errors, if you do a `p operator` after having read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: `gets` isn't doing what you think. It's preserving the trailing newline.

```
irb(main):003:0> gets
hello
=> "hello\n"
```

You need to get rid of the trailing newline.

```
irb(main):004:0> gets.chomp
hello
=> "hello"
```

You can see the impact of this on comparisons:

```
irb(main):013:0> gets.chomp == "hello"
hello
=> true
irb(main):014:0> gets == "hello"
hello
=> false
```

If you want to get rid of all leading or trailing whitespace, you may want to use `#strip`.

```
irb(main):015:0> gets.strip
   +   
=> "+"
```

You'll also need to convert your inputs for operands to numbers.

```
first_number = gets.to_f
```

When converting this way, there is no need to `chomp` off the trailing newline, though you could: `gets.chomp.to_f`.

Answer (score 1):

This program is way longer and more complex then it needs to be. In Ruby operators are just implemented as methods so you can use `Object#send` to perform all of these simple mathematical operations:

```
# This is Ruby - not C/Java/Rust etc - there is no need for a "main" method.
puts "First number: "
first_number = gets.chomp.to_f

# Get the user input in a loop until the user provides a valid operator
operator = loop do
  puts "Operator (+, -, *, /, %): "
  operator = gets.chomp
  if ["+", "-", "*", "/", "%"].include?(operator)
    break operator 
  else
    puts "Invalid operator. Please try again."
  end 
end 

puts "Second number: "
second_number = gets.chomp.to_f
puts "Result: " + first_number.send(operator, second_number)
```

If you want to be able to take more advanced input and map it to methods in this way using a lookup table (a hash) as suggested by Tadman is a good idea.

Comment: While this does incorporate the fix by chomping input, you have advanced some good ideas but not explicitly mentioned the solution to the question being asked.

Comment: Also, as you're using `break` in your loop, there is no need for an `else` at all. You can simply print the error message after the condition, which can be written:  `break operator if ["+", "-", "*", "/", "%"].include?(operator)`.

Comment: Also suggest `puts "Result: #{first_number.send(operator, second_number)}"`

Comment: Thank you @max! I am coming from C/C++/Java/Rust, so yeah that's why I have a main function ;)

Comment: @Chris I know the if/else is slightly redundant but this code is written to be as easy to read and follow as possible.